# BreezeJS and Graph Databases

Tags: neo4j, breeze, graph-databases

Is it possible to use `BreezeJS` with a `Neo4j` (or some other graph db) data store? Is there any sample code for this?

Comment: As is pointed out below, the Breeze User Voice is a good avenue for this. Another alternative is to contact breeze@ideablade.com and ask about having their consulting arm do the work.

Answer (score 2):

Would be cool, perhaps you can ask them here.

https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions

Don't know what it takes to implement a data backend for BreezeJS.

After all Neo4j's API is accessible just with http, so should be supersimple from javascript. There are also some javascript drivers for Neo4j as a starting point.

http://www.neo4j.org/develop/javascript

Answer (score 2):

I have developed neo4j dataservice prototype https://github.com/bogushmax/breeze.dataservice.neo4j. It's interesting because you not needed backend implementation, just client metadata definition.